# redirect 301 htaccess not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have added 301 rederect as follow
Redirect 301 /vc/guides-voyage/vietnam/hanoi /vc/guides-voyage/

But when site load /vc/guides-voyage/vietnam/hanoi it rederect to /vc/guides-voyage//hanoi
Im unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: I just want to rederect
/vc/guides-voyage/vietnam/hanoi
to /vc/guides-voyage/

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `RedirectMatch` rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(vc/guides-voyage)/vietnam/hanoi/?$ /$1
```

Comment: it also rederect to
vc/guides-voyage//hanoi

Comment: I had verified this rule before posting. Make sure you test in a new browser and also keep this as your **first rule** Also do you have any CMS/PHP framework running?

Comment: Hmm Drupal might be forcing `/hanoi` in the end. Can you clear your browser cache run your request in Firebug and see what you get in Net tab.

Comment: Yes sir, it fixed..
Redirect 301 /vc/guides-voyage/belgique/ostende /vc/guides-voyage/  Redirect 301 /vc/guides-voyage/belgique /vc/guides-voyage/

Comment: Previously i added it  Redirect 301 /vc/guides-voyage/belgique /vc/guides-voyage/
Redirect 301 /vc/guides-voyage/belgique/ostende /vc/guides-voyage/

Comment: Oh I see that is very nice, glad to know it worked out.